# Unable to change the increase rate of a variable

Tags: java

I have a Class representing the different resources on a planet.  Upon instantiating an object from the class, the object should increase the number of resources at a constant rate. The rate of production is stored in a variable and could be changed.  I expect that upon changing the production rate,  the actual rate in which the resources are produced should change.  Here is my Resources class:

```
public class PlanetResources implements ResourceObserver {
    
    //baseProducingRate;
    private final int SECONDSINHOUR =3600;
    private final int mmBaseProducingRate =20;
    private final int cBaseProducingRate = 15;
    private final int dBaseProducingRate = 13;
    private final int vBaseProducingRate = 15;
    
    
    //Amount of resources of each type
    private int metallicMicrolattice;
    private int energy;
    private int carbyne;
    private int deuterium; 
    private int vibranium;
    
    //Resources Producing rate
    private int mmProducingRate=this.mmBaseProducingRate;
    private int cProducingRate= this.cBaseProducingRate;
    private int dProducingRate = this.dBaseProducingRate;
    private int vProducingRate = this.vBaseProducingRate;

    
    
    
    public PlanetResources(int mm, int e, int c, int d, int v) {
        super();
        this.metallicMicrolattice = mm;
        this.energy = e;
        this.carbyne = c;
        this.deuterium = d;
        this.vibranium = v;
        
        int delay=2000;

          Timer timer = new Timer();
          timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
              {
                  public void run()
                  {
                      metallicMicrolattice++;
    
                  }
              }, delay, this.SECONDSINHOUR*1000/this.getMmProducingRate());
          
          
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                carbyne++;
            }
        }, delay, this.SECONDSINHOUR*1000/this.cProducingRate);
}
```

HHere is my test codes:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        PlanetResources thePlanetResource = new PlanetResources(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                
        
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome, What would you like to do ?");
        System.out.println("1) visit ship Yard");
        System.out.println("2) visit mines");
        System.out.println("3) manage fleet");
        System.out.println("4) explore galaxy");
        System.out.println("5) exit");
         
        int option = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        if (option==2)
        {
            System.out.println("Here are your current resources:");
            System.out.println(thePlanetResource);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println(thePlanetResource);
            thePlanetResource.setMmProducingRate(10000);
            
        }
        
    }
```

When I ran it, I get:

[image]

The value of metallicMicrollatice should increase much faster after I select 2 the second times(10000/hours) in the provided options. But it still only produced 1 after 10 seconds.

Comment: In multi-thread systems you should use `AtomicInteger` for the variables instead of `int` used in more than one thread (e.g. main and timer thread)instead of int. Otherwise you may run into problems.